# Unable to reset dictionary pointer in trie traversal

Tags: python, loops, iteration

When I try to run the `add_word` method(It is simplified to focus on the area where the issue occurs), I am running into a strange problem. If I attempt to add the word "mud" to the trie, the nodes are created successfully, with the exception of their children. For some reason all of my nodes share the same children dictionary and I can't figure out what is causing this. I am creating a new `TrieNode` whenever I add a new letter to the trie, this should give each child an independent `children` dictionary.
I am using python 3.5
Any idea where I am messing up my pointers?

```
class Trie:
    """Simple Trie Datastructure"""
    def __init__(self, root_val=""):
        self.root = TrieNode(root_val)

    def add_word(self, string):
        current = self.root
        for letter in string:
            new_entry = TrieNode(letter)
            current.children[letter] = new_entry
            current = new_entry

class TrieNode:
    """A Trie Node"""
    def __init__(self, data, children={}):
        self.data = data
        self.children = children
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is in your TrieNode `__init__`. Setting a default argument as a dict/list will cause all of them called without the argument to use the same instance. Easiest solution is to change the method to `def __init__(self, data, children=None):` and the assignment to `self.children = {} if children is None else children`

Comment: Is this described in the documentation anywhere? I don't see where the new nodes could possibly be reaching towards the previous node and assigning the children

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values - the part labeled "Important Warning"